# java.lang.IllegalStateException: InputStream has already been read - do not use InputStreamResource if a stream needs to be read multiple times

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-batch

I am trying to read a file from aws s3 bucket and set it as resource inside my spring batch reader class. When I test the application on aws lambda function I got below error. any suggestion experts?

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: InputStream has already been read - do not use InputStreamResource if a stream needs to be read multiple times
    at org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource.getInputStream(InputStreamResource.java:97) ~[task/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.DefaultBufferedReaderFactory.create(DefaultBufferedReaderFactory.java:34) ~[task/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:266) ~[task/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:146) ~[task/:na]

Class to read from s3 bucket
@Service
public class S3BucketProcessing {
private static final AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();

public InputStreamResource readFile() throws IOException{

   String bucketName = "mybuckey";
   String key = "File.txt";

   S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));    

   return new InputStreamResource(object.getObjectContent());

}
```

Spring batch reader class

```
    @Component
public class MyReader extends FlatFileItemReader<MyEntity> {

    MyLineMapper mapper;
    MyTokenizer tokenizer;
    S3BucketProcessing s3BucketProcessing;

    @Autowired
    public MyReader(MyTokenizer tokenizer, MyLineMapper mapper, S3BucketProcessing s3BucketProcessing) throws Exception{
        LOG.info("CardCustomerNotificationReader constructor");
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.tokenizer = tokenizer;
        this.s3BucketProcessing= s3BucketProcessing;
        this.setResource(s3BucketProcessing.readFile());
        mapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
        this.setLineMapper(mapper);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The docs suggest using ByteArrayResource to cache the content in memory, rather than InputStreamResource.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamResource.html

Just change the returns part like this:

```
//As suggested by berzerk
byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(object.getObjectContent()); 

//Then
return new ByteArrayResource( content );
```

Comment: thanks, can you please share an example how it can implemented in my context.

Comment: Will this cause out of memory issues for higher file?

Comment: Yes. If you hold one big file like 100MB+ in memory, or several smaller files, it's going to take up that much of heap space. You need to see if it is worth having such a lot of data in memory. Also, will it be there for a short while? Or, will it hang around after it is not needed anymore (eg., there is some static reference to it, even though it is not needed anymore)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `InputStreamResource` , you shud return content of the stream may be `byte[]`.

```
byte[] content = IOUtils.toByteArray(object.getObjectContent());
return content ;
```

Comment: then how do I set -> this.setResource(s3BucketProcessing.readFile());

Answer (score 0):

So I had to send in JSON/XML object as Output Stream. I was using the InputStreamResource and was getting the same error as OP.

Here's the solution that worked for me.

```
    @Override
    public Resource dataExportForFieldExtractorModel() {

        ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        byte[] data;
        Resource resource = null;
        try {
            data = xmlMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsBytes(new DataExportResponse());
            resource = new ByteArrayResource(data);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resource;
    }
```

As the resource needs to be `byte[]`, I changed `resource = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));` to
`resource = new ByteArrayResource(data);`.